# Projection map from $\mathbb R^n-(0)$ to $\mathbb RP^{n-1}$ is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry

How do I show that the projection map from $\mathbb R^n-(0)$ to $\mathbb RP^{n-1}$ taking $x$ to its equivalence class $[x]$ is smooth?

Answer (score 1):

Just pick charts and use the definition! What else?

Consider for example the open set $U$ of points of the form $(1:x_1:\cdots:x_n)$ in $P^n$ and the coordinate function $\phi:U\to\mathbb R^n$ such that $\phi(1:x_1:\cdots:x_n)=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Call $f$ your map.

- What is the subset $V=f^{-1}(U)$ of $\mathbb R^n$?
- What is the function $\phi\circ f:V\to\mathbb R^n$?